# How to Redirect users from single.php to another page after downloading digital products in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I posted this same issue on sitepoint forum but no one gave any solution, that's why I am posting this issue here. Hope I found a solution on stackoverflow.

Im developing a worpdress theme for downloading digital products for myself. I want to redirect my users to single.php to another page which will be dynamic. I mean after clicking download button users will redirect to another page where they will see the orginal downloadable link with a thank you message. 
For example: **filehippoDOTcom** (custom site) & **apk4funDOTcom** (wordpress site) .

I saw both of the sites are redirecting users when they click on the download button from single post page. I haven't any clue how they do that. Any suggestions, clue or tutorial will be highly appreciated. If anybody need more info about what I am trying to say then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basicly all you need is to redirect user and issue downloading of the file? That would be really easy to make by simple javascript

Comment: thanks for quick reply, Can you give me the javascript snippest?

Answer (score 0):

This is the javascript to open a new tab with file to download, and to redirect user using javascript

```
<script>
download = "http://www.download-page.com/file.rar";
window.open(download);
window.location.href = "http://www.redirect-page.com";     
</script>
```